# Rails 3.2.13 undefined method `photos_path' with nested resources with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I was hoping someone can give me some insights on how nested resources and more specifically how to tie it with CarrierWave.

I'm getting an error `undefined method 'photos_path'` and am a bit stuck on how do go about getting this to work.

I want to be able to have the following urls

#### Create a new photo

site.com/animal/dog/photos/new

#### Show photo

site.com/animal/dog/photos/my-dog-in-the-park

Should I be using a nested form? any help is much appreciated.

My Routes

```
root to: "home#index"

resources :animal do
  resources :photos
end
```

My home view

```
<%= link_to "Add Dog Photo", new_animal_photo_path(animal_permalink: "dog") %>
```

My _form partial

```
<%= form_for [@animal, @photo], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :animal_permalink %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

My Photo model

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  before_create :set_permalink
  before_update :set_permalink

  belongs_to :dog
  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader

  def set_permalink
    self.permalink = title.parameterize
  end

  def to_param
    permalink.parameterize
  end
end
```

My Animal model

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  has_many :photos

  scope :dog, where(name: "Dog")

  def to_param
    permalink.parameterize
  end
end
```

My PhotoController

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @animal = Animal.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photo."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(photo_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :image, :animal_id)
  end

end
```

Thanks for taking a look. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error looks like it's complaining about routes.  Could the @animal object be nil on /animal/dog/photos/new?

Comment: Hi Swards, thanks for your reply. I'll take a look. I think it may also be with not passing in the animal_id to @photo in the new controller.

Comment: It appears that something important is missing... when are you receiving the error? Can you post a trace of the error? It looks like somewhere in your code you are calling for a path you have not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few adjustments to your code.

Notice I've added an "s" to animal

```
root to: "home#index"

resources :animals do
  resources :photos
end
```

notice I've removed an "s" from animals. I've changed animal_permalink to id because that is the default that would be expected by a nested resource. Also, note that, in your photos controller new method you check for the "id" param, not the animal_permalink param.

```
new_animal_photo_path(id: "dog")
```

In your _form. set the value of the animal_permalink

```
<%= f.hidden_field :animal_permalink, value: @animal.permalink %>
```

This assumes that Photo will be able to recognize the animal_permalink attribute and that you've defined an animal.permalink method/attribute. I'm not familiar with the permalink approach, so you may have to fiddle around a bit, but this should steer you in the right direction (I would normally set the :dog_id/:animal_id attribute).

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Hey cgat! Thanks! This is close to my current working solution. Within  the new action I created an instance variable of @photo = @animal.photos.build(animal_id: @animal_id). Is it okay to have 2 instance variables in one action or should I look to refactor?

Comment: It's okay to have 2 instance variables within an action. The way you had your new action before was fine. By building @photo with the animal_id, all your doing is allowing the form to have access to @photo.animal_id, but you already have access to that value through @animal. Your form will set the parameters for your new object, so if you want to create a photo with animal_id: @animal.id, you have to include a hidden field in your form (of course, you seem to use permalink instead). Also note that `@animal.photos.build(animal_id: @animal_id)` is equal to `@animal.photos.build`